# how to access elements inside of grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, datatemplate

I have a lsitbox which contains a DataTemplate and inside that DataTemplate contains a Grid. I have attached MouseDown ClickListener to Grid. Now I want to get elements of that Grid whenever I click on it.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="222" 
Margin="28,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="244" ItemTemplate="
{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}" BorderThickness="5,1">
        <ListBox.Resources > 
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
                <Grid Width="205" Height="84" MouseDown="ListClickListener">
                    <Label x:Name="nameLabel" Content="{Binding FullName}" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 Width="127" Height="31"/>
                    <Label x:Name="numberLabel" Content="{Binding 
 PhoneNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,31,10,0" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Height="26"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Height="60"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Picture}" 
 Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>    
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

and the method "ListClickListener" inside .cs is as follows:

```
private void ListClickListener(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with those elements? You have chosen an approach that's not the best way to do things with WPF.

Comment: I just want to get the values of those elements i.e Label's Content

Comment: The Label's content is bound to the `FullName` property of the DataContect. Cast `((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext` to the type of the item displayed in the listbox. If the item class is named `MyListBoxItemClass`, use `var vm = (MyListBoxItemClass) ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext; var fullName = vm.FullName;`

Comment: @EdPlunkett sir you are awesome! thank you

Comment: That's what she said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the bound values from the controls, you don't need to touch the controls to do that. In fact, it's much better not to. You'd like to be able to change or rearrange the XAML in the DataTemplate without having to worry about fixing any other code.

You populated the ListBox with a collection of some class. That's the class you want to interact with, not any messy UI stuff. And that's easy in WPF.

For example, the Label's content is bound to the FullName property of the list box item's DataContext. Cast `((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext` to the type of the item displayed in the listbox. Let's say the item class is named `MyListBoxItemClass`:

```
private void ListClickListener(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = (MyListBoxItemClass)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;

    MessageBox.Show("FullName is " + vm.FullName);
}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted!